# Automatically update a Mysql database entry

Tags: mysql

I have a small business and I made a simple mysql database for entering Client name, Datetime, Details, Invoice, Signer, Billing total, Month to date, Year to date, Parts purchased, Parts Purchased year to date. I would like to automatically update the dollar amounts, is this possible? For example: Month to date is $1300.00 the next
entry is for $100.00 leaving a total of $1400.00.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure it's possible, but you need a bit of detail here. How did you create your database and how do you access it? What would trigger an automatic update? Is it done daily, or upon the happening of a certain event? What programming languages are you familiar with?

Comment: Yes, rich we need to know the structure of your tables and the keys of your DB before we can assist any further

Comment: Hi and thank you for responding.
The database has one table and is accessed from my desktop using php.
I use phpmyadmin, mysql cmd or workbench for editing.
The previous dollar amount would be updated upon a new dollar amount
entry.

Comment: The Table:
CREATE TABLE client (
id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Client varchar(40) NOT NULL,
tm datetime NOT NULL default '00:00:00',
Details varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
Invoice varchar(10) NOT NULL, 
Signer varchar (20) NOT NULL,
Billing_Total varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Month_To_Date varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Year_To_Date varchar(20) NOT NULL,
Parts varchar (20) NOT NULL,
Parts_Year_To_Date varchar (20) NOT NULL
)ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: My programming languages include PHP, Mysql ,Python, and Javascript.
If you need anything else let me know.
Thank you, Rich

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to store your information in such a way that it is accurate and efficient. Then use queries to pull the information you are looking for for month to date and year to date.

Lets create a test database and a few tables. You can add columns as needed.

**Test database**

```
CREATE DATABASE stackoverflow;
USE stackoverflow;
```

**Create the table for clients**

This will store all your clients

```
CREATE TABLE clients ( 
  client_id       INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
  client_name     VARCHAR( 70 ) NOT NULL,
  client_details  TEXT
) engine = myisam DEFAULT charset=latin1;
```

**Create the table for parts**

This will store all the parts that you wish to invoice client for

```
CREATE TABLE parts ( 
  part_id         INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
  part_name       VARCHAR( 70 ) NOT NULL,
  part_cost       NUMERIC( 15,2 ),
  description     TEXT
) engine = myisam DEFAULT charset=latin1;
```

**Create the table for invoices**

This will store each invoice that is created. Notice that there is no dollar values or parts here. Doing it this way will reduce the number of times that identical information has to be stored.

> Database normalization is the process of organizing the attributes and tables of a relational database to minimize data redundancy. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

```
CREATE TABLE invoices ( 
  invoice_id      INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
  client_id       INT NOT NULL,
  invoice_date    TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  details         TEXT,
  signer          VARCHAR ( 70 ) NOT NULL
) engine = myisam DEFAULT charset=latin1;
```

**Create table to connect parts to invoices**

Now, lets create a table that will connect our parts table with the invoices. Here we can add information like the notes and quantity that is unique to each item for each invoice. We will use the quantity in our queries to calculate our totals, MTD, YTD, etc.

```
CREATE TABLE invoice_parts (
  id              INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
  part_id         INT NOT NULL,
  invoice_id      INT NOT NULL,
  quantity        INT NOT NULL,
  notes           TEXT
) engine = myisam DEFAULT charset=latin1;
```

**Lets add some test information**

```
-- add some clients
INSERT INTO `clients` (`client_id`, `client_name`, `client_details`) VALUES (NULL, 'chad barker', 'some guy named chad'), (NULL, 'leon tester', 'some guy named leon');

-- add some parts
INSERT INTO `parts` (`part_id`, `part_name`, `part_cost`, `description`) VALUES (NULL, 'can of awesome', '1.99', 'awesome can of awesome'), (NULL, 'can of fail', '.25', 'can filled with failure'), (NULL, 'box of blocks', '24.99', 'box full of cube shaped items called blocks'), (NULL, 'bag of air', '3.99', 'reusable bag filled with useless air');

-- add some invoices
INSERT INTO `invoices` (`invoice_id`, `client_id`, `invoice_date`, `details`, `signer`) VALUES (NULL, '1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'there was an order for some stuff', ''), (NULL, '1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'more stuff needed now', ''), (NULL, '2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'need some stuff quick', ''), (NULL, '2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'don''t ship, just charge me', '');

-- add some invoice/part connections
INSERT INTO `invoice_parts` (`part_id`, `invoice_id`, `quantity`, `notes`) VALUES ('3', '1', '3', 'nothing special'), ('2', '1', '2', 'wants blue'), ('4', '2', '32', 'wants every color'), ('3', '2', '31', 'wants clear'), ('2', '3', '12', 'wants blue'), ('1', '4', '2', 'wants every color'), ('1', '1', '3', 'nothing special'), ('2', '1', '2', 'wants blue'), ('3', '2', '22', 'wants every color'), ('4', '2', '3', 'wants clear'), ('2', '3', '12', 'wants blue'), ('3', '4', '2', 'wants every color');
```

**Query the invoice information**

```
SELECT
  c.client_name,
  i.invoice_date,
  i.details,
  i.signer
FROM invoices i
INNER JOIN clients c
ON i.client_id = c.client_id
WHERE i.invoice_id = 1
;
```

**Query the list of parts**

```
SELECT
  ip.invoice_id,
  p.part_id,
  p.part_name,
  p.part_cost,
  ip.quantity,
  p.part_cost * ip.quantity as total
FROM invoice_parts ip
INNER JOIN parts p
ON ip.part_id = p.part_id
WHERE ip.invoice_id = 1;
```

**Query the total cost of an invoice**

```
SELECT
  ip.invoice_id,
  SUM( p.part_cost * ip.quantity ) as invoice_total
FROM invoice_parts ip
INNER JOIN parts p
ON ip.part_id = p.part_id
WHERE ip.invoice_id = 1;
```

**Query by a selected month**

```
SELECT
  month( i.invoice_date ) as month,
  count( distinct ip.invoice_id ) as invoices,
  count( * ) as parts,
  p.part_cost * ip.quantity as total
FROM invoices i
INNER JOIN invoice_parts ip
ON ip.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
INNER JOIN parts p
ON ip.part_id = p.part_id
WHERE i.client_id = 2
AND month( i.invoice_date ) = 5;
```

**Query by a selected year**

```
SELECT
  year( i.invoice_date ) as year,
  count( distinct ip.invoice_id ) as invoices,
  count( * ) as parts,
  p.part_cost * ip.quantity as total
FROM invoices i
INNER JOIN invoice_parts ip
ON ip.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
INNER JOIN parts p
ON ip.part_id = p.part_id
WHERE i.client_id = 1
AND year( i.invoice_date ) = 2014;
```

Comment: I did not add any special indexing. This will be necessary if you have a lot of information stored.